# Filtrar elementos por medio de una lista

Tags: python, django

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class PostMarcas(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model): 
    postmarcas= models.ForeignKey(PostMarcas,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
    #model
    model= models.CharField(max_length=45)
    #ranuras_ram
    note=models.TextField()
    imagePortada= models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.model
```

A partir del los modelo hice un vista para hacer un filtrado y me muestra los equipos cuya marca es igual,
por ejemplo si escribo `Lenovo` en el `<input>` aparecen todos los equipos de la marca `Lenovo`:

```
def lista(request):
    post= None
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:                     #tabla>>>>>campo>>>metodo>>>>lo que introduces
        post= Post.objects.filter(postmarcas__title__icontains=query)
        
    context ={
            'post':post
         }
    return render(request,'blog/contenido.html',context)
```

Aquí donde solo puedo filtrar con un input.

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/lista/">
 <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Introduce Marca" aria-label="Search" name="q">                       
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" >Marca</button>
</form>
```

Alguna idea de hacer el filtro pero en lugar de escribir el modelo yo seleccione de una lista el modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario usar imput, puedes usar una lista de elementos, que apunten a diferentes url.

1. En tu caso puedes pasar paramentos (marca) a la url  y de esta manera mostrar los resultados.

```
path('lista/<marcas>', views.lista, name='lista' )
```

```
Sitio.com/lista/lenovo
```

2. usar una consulta para filtrar las urls.

```
sitio.com/?marca=lenovo
```

```
query = request.GET.get('marca', '')
```